# What does ifstream::open() really do?

Tags: c++, file-io, filestream, fstream

Consider this code:

```
ifstream filein;

filein.open("y.txt");
```

When I use the `open()` function, what happens?

- Does the file stream itself get opened?
- or does the object's state change to open?
- or both?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filestream being open or closed is represented by it's state.  So if you change the state to open, the filestream is now open.  Like a doorway.  If you open it, you've changed it's state to the open position.  Then you can later close it, which involves changing it's state to the closed position.  Changing its state to open and opening the stream are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if you want to know implementation details or standard requirements - but as for implementation details - it will call the underlying open system call on the operating system.  On Linux for example this is called `open`.  On Windows it is called `CreateFile`.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::ifstream` is set up to own a `std::filebuf` which is a class derived from `std::streambuf`. The stream buffer is managing buffering for streams in a generic way and abstracts the details of how a stream is accessed. For a `std::filebuf` the underlying stream is an operating system file accessed as needed. When `std::ifstream::open()` is called this call is mainly delegated to `std::filebuf::open()` which does the actual work. However, the `std::ifstream` will `clear()` its state bits if the call to `std::filebuf::open()` succeeds and set `std::ios_base::failbit` if the call fails. The file buffer will call the system's method to allocate a file handle and, if successful, arrange for this file handle to be released in its destructor or in the `std::filebuf::close()` function - whatever comes first. When calling `std::ifstream::open()` with the default arguments the system call will check that the file exists, is accessible, not too many file handles are open, etc. There is an `std::ios_base::openmode` parameter which can be used to modify the behavior in some ways and when different flags are used when calling `std::ofstream::open()`.

Whether the call to `std::filebuf::open()` has any other effects is up to the implementation. For example, the implementation could choose to obtain a sequence of bytes and convert them into characters. Since the user can override certain setting, in particular the `std::locale` (see the `std::streambuf::pubimbue()` function), it is unlikely that much will happen prior to the first read, though. In any case, none of the state flags would be affected by the outcome of any operation after opening the file itself.

BTW, the mentioned classes are actually all templates (`std::basic_ifstream`, `std::basic_filebuf`, `std::basic_streambuf`, and `std::basic_ofstream`) which are `typedef`'ed to the names used above for the instantiation working on `char` as a character type. There are similar `typedef`s using a `w` prefix for instantiations working on `wchar_t`. Interestingly, there are no `typedef`s for the `char16_t` and `char32_t` versions and it seems it will be a bit of work to get them instantiated as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you think logically, ifstream is just the stream in which we will get our file contents. The parameters, we provide to ifstream.open() will open the file and mark it as open. When the file is marked as open, it will not allow you to do some operations on file like renaming a file as it is opened by some program. It will allow you to do the same after you close the stream. ifstream - imo is only the helper class to access files.